# How to flash cyanogenmod to my HUAWEI P6 t00

Tags: cyanogenmod, huawei

I have a Chinese phone, Huawei p6-t00. I don't like the stock rom on the phone that much and i want to switch to cyanogenmod. The problem is there is only a version of cyanogenmod for Huawei p6-u06 on the Internet. And when i tried to flash that to my phone, it gave me some kind of error like this rom only supports Huawei p6-u06. So i am wondering is there any way that i can flash cyanogenmod to my phone without damaging it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't find a CM ROM for the p6t00 but i did find [MIUI V5 JB 4.2.2](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2480396) for your device. Download link is at the end of the first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the device-specific nature of Android (it needs specific drivers for it to run on any one given device), it is generally impossible (or illogical, as it seems) to run a build of Android for a specific device on another device.

This also applies to custom ROMs. Unless you can find a CyanogenMod build specifically for your device or for an extremely similar device, there's no way for you to install CM.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am kinda upset for not having a CM for my phone.